# Make Steam windows be always on top?

Tags: steam, window

When I right click the top of steam windows I don't get a context menu. Is there any way to make steam windows (particularly chat windows) be always on top?

Answer (score 0):

You could install devilspie2 or devilspie if you prefer it.

```
#sudo apt-get install devilspie2
#cd ~/.config
#mkdir devilspie2
#cd devilspie2
```

create a script file

```
#nano steam.lua
```

for example if you want to make the friends and main windows always on top, put this lines in the script.

```
if get_application_name()=="Steam" or get_application_name()=="Friends" then
    make_always_on_top();
end
```

For creating scripts its very useful to run devilspie2 with -d option and a script with:

```
debug_print("Window Name: " .. get_window_name());
debug_print("Application name: " .. get_application_name())
```

So you can see the window and application name of the windows opened.

**Note: You could also try with a GUI version of this program [gdevilspie](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gdevilspie/), but it has some problems**

Answer (score 0):

I can open the window menu by pressing ALT+SPACE, which is the keyboard shortcut for the window menu on my Ubuntu (actually PopOS) install.

Once you open the window menu, you can select "Always on Top" as you would normally after right-clicking on the window title.

Here is where I learned this information: https://www.makeuseof.com/keep-a-window-always-on-top-linux/